# Found dtype Double but expected Float

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

BLUF:

`data.x.dtype = torch.float64`
`data.edge_index.dtype = torch.float64' 'data.Utility.dtype = torch.float64`

but when I run

`loss = F.mse_loss(model(graph.x.to(torch.float), graph.edge_index, graph.batch), graph.Utility)`

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/polar/venv/pygeo/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3526, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-58-52a0569421b1>", line 1, in <module>
    loss.backward()
  File "/home/polar/venv/pygeo/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 487, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "/home/polar/venv/pygeo/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 200, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: Found dtype Double but expected Float
```

I even did `model = model.to(dtype=torch.float)` as the other ones state. Still doesn't work!

Please don't comment, write an answer so I can mark it as the answer, thank you.

Comment: More code needs to be shown to definitively pinpoint the issue you're having.  This is still not a Minimal Reproducible Example. 

You can try explicitly converting your model to torch.float64 to match the dtype of your tensors:  ```model =  model.to(dtype=torch.float64)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks similar to package/python version dependency issues I've hit in the past.

Looks like you have a package called "torch" and are running python 3.10.

Might be worth checking which version of torch you've got and checking the package's docs for which python versions are supported, then up or downgrading either the package or your python version so they match.

Hope it helps!